# Merge two vectors and get a list of vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I have two vectors:

```
u <- c(1, 3, 5)
v <- c(2, 4, 6)
```

I want to combine then into a result `res`, which has to be a list of two-dimensional vectors.

Does there exist a way to do the following intelligently?

```
res <- list(c(u[1], v[1]), c(u[1], v[2]), c(u[1], v[3]), c(u[2], v[1]) ... )
```

Edited the question, trying to better explain what I want.

Comment: I don't get how vectorResult should look. The first example seems to consist of the pair [v1[1], v2[1]], but what is the second one? Can you clarify it? What dimension do you expect?

Comment: Anyway, a vector in R is supposed to have a atomic type (see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects)). You either need a list or matrix type.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the question to properly show the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something resembling like a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) for the vectors

```
> u
[1] 1 3 5
> v
[1] 2 4 6
```

Like user hrbrmstr explained, one can get combinations this way

```
> r = expand.grid(v, u)
> r
  Var1 Var2
1    2    1
2    4    1
3    6    1
4    2    3
5    4    3
6    6    3
7    2    5
8    4    5
9    6    5
```

note that I switched `u` and `v` to fit your target data structure.
Then I pick the two column vectors

```
> x <- r[[2]]
> y <- r[[1]]
> x
[1] 1 1 1 3 3 3 5 5 5
> y
[1] 2 4 6 2 4 6 2 4 6
```

and their length

```
> n <- length(x)
> n
[1] 9
```

then the list gets created with `n` elements

```
> res <- vector(mode="list", length=n)
```

Finally the list gets filled:

```
> for (i in 1:n) {
+ res[[i]] = c(x[i], y[i])
+ }
```

which yields

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 6

[[4]]
[1] 3 2

[[5]]
[1] 3 4

[[6]]
[1] 3 6

[[7]]
[1] 5 2

[[8]]
[1] 5 4

[[9]]
[1] 5 6

>
```

Maybe there is a faster way, but I believe this gives your intended data structure.

Comment: This is almost what I needed. Thanks for the answer, it helped me to get to the solution! Just for your concern, the solution was: `for(a in v){ for(b in u){ res[[length(res)+1]] <- c(a, b) } }`

Comment: OK, I am glad you got it. I learned as well from this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

unless you **need* the `[3,2]` in position 4, can you settle for the results of `expand.grid`?

```
v1 <- c(1,3,5)
v2 <- c(2,4,6)
as.matrix(expand.grid(v1,v2))
##       Var1 Var2
##  [1,]    1    2
##  [2,]    3    2
##  [3,]    5    2
##  [4,]    1    4
##  [5,]    3    4
##  [6,]    5    4
##  [7,]    1    6
##  [8,]    3    6
##  [9,]    5    6
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the question to put more details.